# Single text field for database query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to be able to enter any the following types of information into 
into a single text field.

1. customer name (ie first and last name).
2. customer phone number.  (including area code)
3. customer email address.
4. customer service ticket number.
5. customer product serial number.

How it works so far is that I have 5 different PHP files
one for each type of information to be entered.

this works for each if I keep changing the function requestCustomerInfo() see below.

I am using Ajax XHR request - working example below:
this is in the **index.php** page.

```
function handleHttpResponse() {    
    if (http.readyState == 4) { 
      if(http.status==200) { 
         var results=http.responseText; 
         document.getElementById('divCustomerInfo').innerHTML = results; 
      } 
    } 
}



function requestCustomerInfo() {      

   //look up info by customer name
   var url = "GetCustomerName.php?name="; // The server-side script
   var sName = document.getElementById("CustomerId").value; 
   http.open("GET", url + escape(sName),  true);  


   //look up info by customer email 
   //var url = "GetCustomerEmail.php?email="; // The server-side script 
   //var sEmail = document.getElementById("CustomerId").value;
   //http.open("GET", url + escape(sEmail), true);


   //look up info by customer phone number
   //var url = "GetCustomerPhone.php?phone="; // The server-side script
   //var sPhone = document.getElementById("CustomerId").value; 
   //http.open("GET", url + escape(sPhone), true);  


   //look up info by customer product serial number
   //var url = "GetProductSerialNumber.php?serial="; // The server-side script 
   //var sSerial = document.getElementById("CustomerId").value; 
   //http.open("GET", url + escape(sSerial), true);


   //look up info by customer product service ticket number 
   //var url = "GetServiceTicket.php?ticket="; // The server-side script
   //var sTicket = document.getElementById("CustomerId").value;
   //http.open("GET", url + escape(sTicket), true);


    http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse; 
    http.send(null); 
 } 

 function getHTTPObject() { 
    var xmlhttp; 

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){ 
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
         if (!xmlhttp){ 
             xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
         } 
   } 
   return xmlhttp; 
 } 

 var http = getHTTPObject(); // We create the HTTP Object 

//This is the look up by customer name PHP file: - typical of the 5 php files.

<?php 
    //customer ID 
    $sName = $_GET["name"]; 
    $q= $_GET["q"];  

    //variable to hold customer info 
    $sInfo = ""; 

    //database information 
    $sDBServer = "localhost"; 
    $sDBName = "customers"; 
    $sDBUsername = "root"; 
    $sDBPassword = "root"; 

    //create the SQL query string 
    $sQuery = "SELECT c.customerId, c.name, c.address, c.city, c.state, c.zip, c.phone, c.email, t.ticket 
              FROM customers c
              left join serviceTicket t
              on c.customerId = t.customerId
              WHERE  name = '$sName' ";
              //  OR c.email = '$sEmail'
              //  OR c.phone = '$sPhone'
              //  OR t.ticket = '$sTicket'
              //  OR t.serial = '$sSerial'";

    //make the database connection 
    $oLink = mysql_connect($sDBServer,$sDBUsername,$sDBPassword); 
    @mysql_select_db($sDBName) or $sInfo = "Unable to open database"; 

    if($sInfo == '') { 
    $bg = ($bg=='#ffffff' ? '#FCFCFC' : '#ffffff');
        if($oResult = mysql_query($sQuery) and mysql_num_rows($oResult) > 0) { 
          $aValues = mysql_fetch_array($oResult,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
            $sInfo = "Customer account number: ".$aValues['customerId']."<br />".
                     "Customer name: ".$aValues['name']."<br />".
                     "Address: ".$aValues['address']."<br />". 
                     "City: ".$aValues['city']."<br />".
                     "State: ".$aValues['state']."<br />". 
                     "Postal code: ".$aValues['zip']."<br />".
                     "Phone: ".$aValues['phone']."<br /><br />". 
               "<a href=\"mailto:".$aValues['email']."\">".$aValues['email']."</a><br/><br/>"; 
        } else { 
            $sInfo = "Customer with Name $sName doesn't exist."; 
        } 
    }

?>

    <div id="divInfoToReturn"> <?php echo $sInfo ?> </div>  //display above info

<?php 

     $cid =  $aValues['customerId'].'<br/>';   //customerId from above

    //select list dropdown for selecting a particular customer product.
    $ticketquery = "Select * from serviceTicket where customerId = ".$aValues['customerId']."";             
        $srvcticket = mysql_query($ticketquery);
        echo '<span class="selecttickettext">';
        echo '<select name="tickets" onchange="showUser(this.value)" id="select">';
        echo '<option selected ="">Select a Customer Product and Service Ticket</option>';
        echo "<option>------------------------------------</option>";
        echo '</span>';
        while ($ticketrow = mysql_fetch_array($srvcticket)){
                $id = $ticketrow['id'];
                $ticket = $ticketrow['ticket'];
                $product = $ticketrow['product'];
                $serial = $ticketrow['serial'];
                $model = $ticketrow['model'];
                $computer = $ticketrow['computer'];
                $os = $ticketrow['os'];
                $issue = $ticketrow['issue'];
                $docs = $ticketrow['docs'];
                $cso = $ticketrow['cso'];
        echo "<option value='$id'> "." $product "." $ticket";
        };
        echo "</select>\n";

    mysql_close($oLink); 

    //create the SQL query string 
    $pQuery = "Select * from serviceTicket where customerId = '$cid'";

    //make the database connection 
    $oLink = mysql_connect($sDBServer,$sDBUsername,$sDBPassword); 
    @mysql_select_db($sDBName) or $pInfo = "Unable to open database"; 

    if($pInfo == '') { 
        if($oResult = mysql_query($pQuery) and mysql_num_rows($oResult) > 0) { 
          $aValues = mysql_fetch_array($oResult,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
            $pInfo = "Service ticket:" . " " .$aValues['ticket']."<br />".
                     "Product:" . " " .$aValues['product']."<br />". 
                     "Serial number:" . " " .$aValues['serial']."<br />".
                     "Product model:" . " " .$aValues['model']."<br />". 
                     "Computer brand:" . " " .$aValues['computer']."<br />".
                     "Operating OS:" . " " .$aValues['os']."<br />". 
                     "Printer issue:" . " " .$aValues['issue']."<br />". 
                     "KB docs:" . " " .$aValues['docs']."<br />".
                     "Customer service order:" . " " .$aValues['cso']."<br />";
        } else { 
            $pInfo = "Customer product for $sName not found."; 
        } 
    } 
?>
```

This is the  **select user js file**: 
used for passing info to get user for select dropdown.

```
// JavaScript Document
var xmlhttp;

function showUser(str)
{
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
  return;
  }
var url="getuser.php";
url=url+"?q="+str;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return null;
}
```

This is the  **getuser js** file: 
for populating production info section.

```
<?php

//database information 
$sDBServer = "localhost"; 
$sDBName = "customers"; 
$sDBUsername = "root"; 
$sDBPassword = "root";

$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect($sDBServer, $sDBUsername, $sDBPassword);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db( $sDBName );

$sql="SELECT * FROM serviceTicket WHERE id = '".$q."'";  

//$sql="SELECT * FROM serviceTicket WHERE id = 3";  

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<div class="productInfo">Product Information </div>';

  echo  "Product : " . $row['product'].'<br/>' ;

  echo  "Serial number : " . $row['serial'] .'<br/>';
  echo  "Model number : " . $row['model'].'<br/>' ;

  echo "Computer brand : " . $row['computer'] .'<br/>';
  echo "Operating system  : " . $row['os'].'<br/>';

  echo '<div class="productIssue">Issues and Resolution documents </div>';

  echo "Product issues" .'<br/>'. $row['issue'].'<br/>';

  echo "Knowledge base docs : " . $row['docs'] .'<br/>';
  echo "Customer service order : " . $row['cso'].'<br/>';

  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

All the above is working, but I want to be able to have a single field to look up
customer information.

working version so far:
http://www.stevenjsteele.com/ajaxmysqljquery/

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have some serious vulnerabilities including SQL injection in this code. I recommend using a DB access class that supports/emulates parameterization like ('SELECT ... WHERE textField = ?', $str). Eg. Zend_Db and ADOdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about some kind of regular expression? You would test if it is true against some expression.

There a lot of pre-made expressions you can use.

Email you could google one,
Phone number depends on how they are going to be inputted. (10 digits or xxx-xxx-xxxx)
Serial if its a fixed length as well but with numbers and letters
First and last name would be letters with a space in between or just letters
ticket number could be a fixed length number as well.

You could check and see which one it matches and then pass it off to the correct file.

Comment: Note that he meant to write "Regular Expression" aka "Regex" which will make it easier to google this.  The O'Reilly book "Mastering Regular Expressions" is a good reference on this topic.

Comment: You're correct. not sure why i was thinking regression. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I've have googled on Regex, this may be the way go. Phone number will 10 didgit no dash or spaces. Serial will not be fixed length and will be alpha-numeric, ticket will not be fixed length and will be alpha-numeric also. sounds like more research on Regex is thw way to go at least for now, I am also looking into this article http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Ajax-in-Prototype.id-306214.html

Comment: need to do more research on this. Have removed file from server. Thanks all.

Comment: The only other thing you could do is try to query each field. which looking at the query above, it looks like thats commented out. It may return multiple records though. Where you have OR commented out. You would pass in the string that was passed from the field. Phone number, serial, ticket could all just see if it's exactly that. Name depending on how you have it, you could do LIKE.